# Geometry question

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image: figure]
In the given figure , AP, BQ and CR are perpendicular to line AC. And AP=$x$ , BQ=$y$, CR=$z$ then find the value of $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{z}$ in terms of $y$.
I have no idea how to solve it. But the limitation is this is to do with the use of similarity concepts. Don't use trigonometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

y/z = AB / (AB+BC)

y/x = BC / (AB+BC)

y/z + y/x = AB/(AB+BC) + BC/(AB+BC) = 1

1/z + 1/x = 1/y

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Side-Splitter Theorem](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-solve-similar-triangle-problems-with-the-si.html)   can write $y/z = AB/AC$ and $y/x = BC/AC$. From there the answer is $1/x + 1/z = 1/y$.